# How do I read attributes using jaxb?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, xml-deserialization

Given this XML:

```
<response>
    <detail Id="123" Length="10" Width="20" Height="30" />
</response>
```

This is what I have now, but it is not working (I'm getting empty result):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
public class MyResponse {
    List<ResponseDetail> response;
    //+getters +setters +constructor
}

public class MyResponseDetail {
    Integer Id;
    Integer Length;
    Integer Width;
    Integer Height;
    //+getters +setters
}
```

I'm making a call to a remote service using `RestOperations` and I want to parse the `<detail ..>` element. I've tried passing both `MyResponse` and `MyResponseDetail` classes to `RestOperations` but the result is always empty.

What should my object structure look like to match that XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to annotate your classes like that:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {

    private List<Detail> detail;

    public void setDetail(List<Detail> detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
    public List<Detail> getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

}

public class Detail {

    private String id;
    /* add other attributes here */

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 - Edited your answer to fix the accessors on the `Response` class, and remove unnecessary annotations.

Comment: Thanks for improving my answer!