# get attribute of XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, attributes

I have the following xml file:

```
<TEST>
<NEED ID="0">OK</NEED>
</TEST>
```

I simply want to get the attribute of the tag NEED and save it into an Integer variable.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TEST")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Resp {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ID", required = true) 
    protected Integer resultId;
    // getters, setters, constructor
}
```

How to receive the ID value?

Comment: Provide a [getter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work).

Comment: I have getter and setter

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232795/how-do-i-read-attributes-using-jaxb

Comment: @ninjaxelite The code you provided does _not_ have any getter or setter. So, you don't have them.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403472/querying-xml-in-java-relationally/39409131#39409131

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDom parser.

```
File inputFile = new File("input.xml");
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

Document document = saxBuilder.build(inputFile);
Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

List<Element> aList = classElement.getChildren();


for (int temp = 0; temp < aList.size(); temp++) {    
            Element student = aList.get(temp);

            Attribute attribute =  student.getAttribute("ID");
            System.out.println("ID : " 
               + attribute.getValue() ); 

         }
```